# How to run react-native in expo?

Tags: react-native, npm, ip-address, expo

I am getting started with react-native today but have run into an issue when trying to launch in expo app. My phone and my computer are connected to the same wifi, I am using a windows machine but am running ubuntu, and using an android device.

When I run `npm start` everything seems to work fine, but when I scan the QR code on my phone I get the eroor message `Something went wrong. Could not load exp://ip:19000. Network response timed out.` In the error log, it reads `Uncaught error: java.net.SocketTimeoutException: connection timed out`.

I have tried following other threads on different websites but have been unable to find solution. I set `REACT_NATIVE_PACKAGER_HOSTNAME` to my IP address, and I can see that it has changed when I run `npm start`, but it still doesn't fix the problem.

Any ideas on solutions?

Answer (score 0):

Your windows firewall is causing the problem. Try disabling ur firewall.

Comment: Even when disabling it does not work, same errors. Plus I don't think this would be a sustainable solution

Comment: It's a temporary workaround. Perhaps you should be checking whether your ports are actually open when you run `npm start` from ubuntu on windows.

Answer (score 0):

If the app is not running in `Expo` the problem most likely is within your network. For example, most school and work networks are not fully open and most likely block ports needed for `Expo` to run.

If you are on your own WiFi network, try opening ports and disabling firewalls within your router.

I **hope** that helped you out.